# Change Filename Case DOS Batchfile

Tags: batch-file, case, filenames, dos

I have worked out to change the case of filenames to lowercase using a DOS batch file using the code below, but I was wondering if someone could help me add to include code to capitalise the first letter of each file name as well.

George :-)

```
pushd %varFolderTemp%
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.*) do (
set "filename=%%~nf"
set filename=!filename:A=a!
set filename=!filename:B=b!
set filename=!filename:C=c!
set filename=!filename:D=d!
set filename=!filename:E=e!
set filename=!filename:F=f!
set filename=!filename:G=g!
set filename=!filename:H=h!
set filename=!filename:I=i!
set filename=!filename:J=j!
set filename=!filename:K=k!
set filename=!filename:L=l!
set filename=!filename:M=m!
set filename=!filename:N=n!
set filename=!filename:O=o!
set filename=!filename:P=p!
set filename=!filename:Q=q!
set filename=!filename:R=r!
set filename=!filename:S=s!
set filename=!filename:T=t!
set filename=!filename:U=u!
set filename=!filename:V=v!
set filename=!filename:W=w!
set filename=!filename:X=x!
set filename=!filename:Y=y!
set filename=!filename:Z=z!
ren "%%~nxf" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
popd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if your code is the optimal (may be it is) solution but I haven't changed it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.*) do (
set "filename=%%~nf"
set filename=!filename:A=a!
set filename=!filename:B=b!
set filename=!filename:C=c!
set filename=!filename:D=d!
set filename=!filename:E=e!
set filename=!filename:F=f!
set filename=!filename:G=g!
set filename=!filename:H=h!
set filename=!filename:I=i!
set filename=!filename:J=j!
set filename=!filename:K=k!
set filename=!filename:L=l!
set filename=!filename:M=m!
set filename=!filename:N=n!
set filename=!filename:O=o!
set filename=!filename:P=p!
set filename=!filename:Q=q!
set filename=!filename:R=r!
set filename=!filename:S=s!
set filename=!filename:T=t!
set filename=!filename:U=u!
set filename=!filename:V=v!
set filename=!filename:W=w!
set filename=!filename:X=x!
set filename=!filename:Y=y!
set filename=!filename:Z=z!
ren "%%~nxf" "!filename!%%~xf"
)

for %%l in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
        set filename=%%~nf
        if /i "!filename:~0,1!" EQU "%%~l" (
            ren "%%~nxf" "%%l!filename:~1!%%~xf"
        )
    ) 
)
endlocal
popd
```

Comment: Hi npocmaka Thankyou so much for your help. Yes the code is not optimal but I understand it! However now that I see your code I will look at making it more efficient. Thanks again. George :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may make good use of the fact that substring replacement is *not* case sensitive, that is, the case is ignored in the source characters, but preserved in the replacement characters:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Capitalize.bat: Change file names with first letter uppercase, the rest 

lowercase

for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set "filename=%%~Nf"
   rem Change all letters to lowercase
   for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%a=%%a!"
   )
   rem Change first letter to uppercase
   set "letter=!filename:~0,1!"
   for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "letter=!letter:%%A=%%A!"
   )
   ren "%%f" "!letter!!filename:~1!%%~Xf"
)
```

Comment: I like your coding Aacini - you often have methods that are very elegant, though sometimes are harder to decipher.  I just wanted to mention that a `!` character will break this.

Comment: Thanks, foxi! Yes, the problem of `!` in filenames is the same as always, but I don't like to mention it because the majority of users have not such case. If someone have this problem, and ask for a solution, then is time to explain the environment toggling technique `;-)`